# Attempting to install AlmaLinux shows this really weird thing as a zombie partition

Tags: linux, centos, partition, system-installation, alma-linux

So this morning I had written AlmaLinux 9.1 iso file to my flash drive to do this install. I had previously used the same flash drive to install CentOS 7 a couple days ago but now I wanted to upgrade to AlmaLinux.

But unfortunately, there was a zombie partition which was the flash drive itself, which shows up as "Unknown" on the partitions page.

[image]

Also you can see in the screenshot above that choosing that partition shows that it is indeed the USB stick, as shown in the top right. And you can also see the Label of "AlmaLinux-9-1-x86_64", proving that it is indeed the flash drive that it is booted from.

**First attempt**

The first time, I decided to ignore it and proceed with the install. Well it corrupted both the install and the flash drive, which then disappeared and I had to physically remove and format the USB stick because it could no longer be recognized in lsblk or parted or anything, even though it showed attached as a USB device in dmesg. So weird.

**Second attempt**

So then I just downloaded another copy of AlmaLinux 9.1 again and this time burned it to the flash drive a different way (the first time I had used dd, this time I used a boot drive creator). I also had formatted the corrupted drive to be empty.

But on boot I find the same zombie partition. I am nearly certain it will result in the same behavior, because this isn't supposed to be there. Also, the AlmaLinux install couldn't see two of my drives either, but that was ok because I didn't need to install them. But this isn't normal.

I definitely did not select it in the drives screen. I double-checked and triple-checked.

Here is what it is supposed to look like, on the left is the CentOS install.
In the bottom right it says 1 disk selected, because it thinks that the flash drive is a partition on the selected disk. Weird.
You can see that on the AlmaLinux, space on the same disk is reduced by 30GB, which is the size of the flash drive. It thinks the flash drive that it's booted from is a partition on the drive that is selected.

[image]

There seems to be some bug with the AlmaLinux install disc. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: That (the alma installer) is not a partition, it's a DEVICE. Note how the hdd is `sda`. `sdc` is the USB device.

Comment: But it's not a selected device. When more than one device is selected (this server has 7 drives), the devices show under a different GROUP, not under the Unknown particitions group. This does NOT show on the CentOS 7 install, only on the AlmaLinux 8 and 9 installs. Also, the AlmaLinux installs cannot see two of my 5 drives, whereas the CentOS installer can see all 5 drives and allow me to select any of them. The AlmaLinux installer is bugged.